# input type="email" set value in asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How can I assign value to

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" required="" autofocus="" name="txtEmailId" id="txtEmailId" />
```

in the code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `runat="server"` with markup

```
<input type="email" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" required="" autofocus="" name="txtEmailId" id="txtEmailId" />
```

Now on code behind you can access it via `txtEmailId`

As Html 5 control is not available using runat attribute. You can directly use the TextBox like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailId" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: since it is HTML5 control, `type=email` is not available in the code behind even if add `runat=server`

Comment: @James123 it's a good point.I totally missed that. So in this case you can directly use the textbox with `TextMode="Email"`. see the update.